# Одновременно создать и перейти в созданную папку на Windows в командной строке

Tags: windows, cmd

Есть проблемка. В командной строке есть такие команды: mkdir(создать папку) и cd(перейти в папку). Так вот, как совместить эти 2 команды? Есть ли такая команда, либо ее нужно создавать самому. Я знаю на Линукс нужно "поколдовать" с файлом .bashrc , но на виндовс такого файла попросту нет. Что делать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Для того чтобы выполнить несколько команд из одной командной строки,
>   нужно объединить их с помощью символа условной обработки:
>
> `команда1 & команда2` — Используется для разделения нескольких команд в одной командной строке. В `cmd.exe` выполняется первая команда,
>   затем вторая команда.
>
> `команда1 && команда2` — Запускает команду, стоящую за символом `&&`, только если команда, стоящая перед этим символом была выполнена
>   успешно. В `cmd.exe` выполняется первая команда. Вторая команда
>   выполняется, только если первая была выполнена успешно.
>
> `команда1 || команда2` — Запускает команду, стоящую за символом `||`, только если команда, стоящая перед символом `||` не была выполнена. В
>   `cmd.exe` выполняется первая команда. Вторая команда выполняется, только
>   если первая не была выполнена (полученный код ошибки превышает ноль).

Для вашего примера:

```
mkdir some_dir && cd some_dir
```